# Extending behaviors when extending views

Tags: marionette

The task is:
MyViewX uses BehaviorA and B
MyViewY extends MyViewX,
and uses all behaviors in MyViewX, plus BehaviorC

```
// The following code works
// 
var MyViewX = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    behaviors: {
       BehaviorA: {},
       BehaviorB: {}
    }
});

var MyViewY = MyViewX.extend({
    behaviors: {
       BehaviorA: {},
       BehaviorB: {},
       BehaviorC: {}
    }
});
```

**The question:** how to make use of the behaviors definition in X, so that in Y I do not need to repeat A and B?

```
// this is not good.  It overrides X.  Y has only C
var MyViewY = MyX.extend({
    behaviors: {
       BehaviorC: {}
    }
});


// maybe something like this?
// but how exactly to get X's behaviors here?
var MyViewY = MyViewX.extend({
    behaviors: _.extend{
      BEHAVIORS_OF_THE_SUPER_OF_THE_CURRENT_CLASS,
      { BehaviorC: {} }
    }
});


// this gives no errors, 
// but A and B do not behave, as if they are not used.
//
var MyViewY = MyViewX.extend({
  behaviors: { BehaviorC: {} },
  initialize: function () {
      var b = this.behaviors;
      this.behaviors = _.extend( 
          MyViewY.__super__.behaviors,
          b
      );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `MyViewX`'s behaviors by accessing it's `prototype`. Using your ideal solution the following should work:

```
var MyViewY = MyViewX.extend({
  behaviors: _.extend({},
    MyViewX.prototype.behaviors,
    { BehaviorC: {} }
  );
});
```

The reason the last example doesn't work is because Marionette Behaviors are added to a view in the Marionette.View constructor which takes place before the Backbone.View constructor which calls `initialize` at the end.

Comment: This solution work while having a side effect: it also adds `BehaviorC` to  `MyViewX.prototype.behaviors`.  Now `MyViewX` has `BehaviorC`.  I am in a situation where `X` must not have `C`.

Comment: Ah you're right, this will mutate the original `behaviors` object. I've updated the answer to reflect a way that will not have side effects.